# How do I overwrite a trait in PHP?

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

I have 2 **classes** and a **trait**:

*TraitRunner.php*

```
use Traits\Create;

class TraitRunner {
    ...
}
```

*Controller.php*

```
use TraitRunner;

class Controller {
    public function __construct()
        ...
        $this->something = app()->make(TraitRunner()::class);
        ...
    }
}
```

*FooController.php*

```
use Controller;

class FooController extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

I need to overwrite a trait method. I can make a new trait and edit a TraitRunner.php, adding this:

```
use Create, MyCreate {
    MyCreate::fooMethod insteadof Create;
}
```

Actual use of trait's methods is somewhere deeper in the code, so I simplified it for clearness.

The problem is that I can't change *TraitRunner.php* and *Controller.php* files as they're in **vendor** directory. Please suggest what and where should I add if I can edit only *FooController.php*.

Comment: none of your example classes actually use a trait

Comment: I thing you can just `use MyCreate;` in the FooController.php, and if MyCreate has methods that also are given in Create, they will be overridden.

Comment: @NDM the actual use of trait's methods is deeper in another code, I simplified it for clearness, though it shouldn't affect the answer to my question.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions no I can't because this trait has methods that conflict with methods of Controller class.

Answer (score 2):

**Are Traits overridden by other Traits?
Yes! And no, *if done the wrong way* ;-)**

```
trait t1 {
     function abc(){
        print __METHOD__.'<br>';
    }
}
class a {
    use t1;
}
trait t2 {
    function abc(){
        print __METHOD__.'<br>';
        //parent::abc();  //will call t1:abc() again, if exists and is called
    }
}
class b extends a {
    use t2;
}
//works
(new a)->abc();//prints t1::abc<br>
//works
(new b)->abc();//prints t2::abc<br>


//But this wont work. (Did not realay know why)
class c {
   use t1,t2;
}
//So this fails  (both traits are used in the same class definition)
(new c)->abc();
//Fatal error:  Trait method abc has not been applied, because there are collisions
```

Traits can implement other traits.

```
trait t1 {
    function x(){}
}
trait t2 {
    use t1;
    function x(){}
}
```

Have a nice day

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Martin Sure it does, Question was `How do I overwrite a trait in PHP?`

Comment: @Martin To make fully clear create the trait MyCreate and just use it in class FooController. That will then override all methods defined by Create. Do you need more explanation?

Comment: No it doesn't, because question consists not only of heading.

Comment: I don't need more explanation from you personally.

Comment: @Martin Then go with the first comment on your question. And mybe read the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create differen trait to override method from trait.

From PHP Doc:

> The precedence order is that members from the current class override
>   Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

So, for example, this code:

```
trait TraitRunner {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'TraitRunner method';
    }
}

class Controller {
    use TraitRunner;
}

class FooController extends Controller {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'FooController method ';
    }
}

$o = new FooController();
$o->sayHello();
```

Will give:

```
FooController method
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in this situation. I don't know exactly why: maybe because of the way TraitRunner is used in Controller class, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Through the experiments I've found this method:

1.- create a new trait MyCreate with an overwritten method fooMethod

2.- edit FooController.php:

```
use vendor\Traits\Create
use app\Traits\MyCreate

class TraitRunner extends vendor\TraitRunner {
    use Create, MyCreate {
        MyCreate::fooMethod insteadof Create;
    }
}

class Controller extends vendor\Controller {
    // the following code is the place where TraitRunner is used, so we have to put it here
    public function __construct()
        ...
        $this->something = app()->make(TraitRunner()::class);
        ...
    }
}

class FooController extends Controller { ...
```

If there is a more adequate way, you're very welcome to suggest it. Though this way works well.